# Specify one parameter for Func at declaration time and another at invoke/execution time

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, delegates, func

From my research I have not found any evidence that this is possible, so I was wondering if there a way to do this or the next cleanest solution?

I want to avoid having to pass another argument to my generic function to keep it clean and improve modularity.

Consider the following generic looping function which invokes a predicate function to check a certain condition while looping a collection:

```
Private Sub LoopAndApplyCondition(Of T)(ByVal collection As IDataCollection, ByVal condition As Func(Of T, String, Boolean), ByRef result As List(Of T))
  If Not collection.ActiveItems Is Nothing And collection.Count > 0 Then
    For Each record In collection
   '***
   '*** I would like to pass in the record into the predicate function here ***
   '***
        Dim meetsCondition As Boolean = condition.Invoke(CType(record, T))
        If meetsCondition Then result.Add(CType(record, T))
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

This is what defines the predicate function(condition) and calls this generic looping function, it has the attributeName field which is what I would like to pass into the predicate function.

```
Public Function AllEditableRecords(Of T)(ByVal collection As IDataObjectCollection, ByVal attributeName As String) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of T)
    '***
    '*** I would like to pass in the attributeName field to the predicate function here ***
    '***
    Dim condition As Func(Of T, String, Boolean) = AddressOf CheckIfRecordIsEditable
    LoopAndApplyCondition(Of T)(collection, condition, result)
  Return result
End Function
```

This is the signature of the predicate function:

```
Private Function CheckIfRecordIsEditable(Of T)(record As T, attributeName As String) As Boolean
  'Returns conditionResult
End Function
```

So to summarise, I would like to pass in the string parameter to **CheckIfRecordIsEditable** via the **AllEditableRecords** function and the generic **record** parameter via the **LoopAndApplyCondition**.

I don't think its possible, but please prove me wrong.
I'm happy to also accept an answer in C#, but VB.NET preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to define parameters for delegates while declaring them.

However, what is possible is to encapsulate the Func and its parameters in its own class:

```
Public Class RecordCondition(Of T)
    Public Property CheckConditionHandler As Func(Of T, String, Boolean)
    Public Property AttributeName As String
End Class
```

Create the `RecordCondition` in **AllEditableRecords**:

```
Public Function AllEditableRecords(Of T)(ByVal collection As IDataObjectCollection, ByVal attributeName As String) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of T)

    Dim recordCondition As New RecordCondition(Of T) With {.CheckConditionHandler = AddressOf CheckIfRecordIsEditable, .AttributeName=attributeName}
    LoopAndApplyCondition(Of T)(collection, recordCondition, result)
    Return result
End Function
```

Call `CheckConditionHandler` in **LoopAndApplyCondition**:

```
Private Sub LoopAndApplyCondition(Of T)(ByVal collection As IDataCollection, ByVal condition As RecordCondition(Of T), ByRef result As List(Of T))
    If Not collection.ActiveItems Is Nothing And collection.Count > 0 Then
        For Each record In collection
            Dim meetsCondition As Boolean = condition.CheckConditionHandler(record, condition.AttributeName) 
            If meetsCondition Then result.Add(CType(record, T))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**CheckIfRecordIsEditable** does not change.

Comment: Yes I agree, this is probably the next best thing to maintain encapsulation, thanks!